# Nested function unexpected behaviour in Swift?

Tags: swift5, swift-playground, nested-function

I was trying the following example for Nested functions but I am getting unexpected behaviour:

```
func chooseStepFunction(value: Int, backward: Bool) -> (Int) -> Int {
    
    print("Current value: \(value)")
    
    func stepForward(input: Int) -> Int {
        print("plus from \(input)");
        return input + 1
    }
    func stepBackward(input: Int) -> Int {
        print("minus from \(input)");
        return input - 1
    }
    return backward ? stepBackward : stepForward
}
var currentValue = 4
let moveNearerToZero = chooseStepFunction(value: currentValue, backward: currentValue > 0)
// moveNearerToZero now refers to the nested stepForward() function
while currentValue != -2 {
    print("\(currentValue)... ")
    currentValue = moveNearerToZero(currentValue)
}
```

I was trying with backward and forward nested function but getting the following result:

```
Current value: 4
4... 
minus from 4
3... 
minus from 3
2... 
minus from 2
1... 
minus from 1
0... 
minus from 0
-1... 
minus from -1
```

Like, Every time I am modifying the `currentValue` and every time I am calling the `chooseStepFunction` but in console the `currentValue` inside `chooseStepFunction` function is executing only once but the `currentValue` inside while loop is executing evrytime then why the `chooseStepFunction` is skipping printing the value. In my sense the expected result will be:

```
Current value: 4
4... 
minus from 4
3... 
minus from 3
2... 
minus from 2
1... 
minus from 1
0...
plus from 0
1... 
minus from 1
0...
plus from 0
1... 
minus from 1
0...
..........
```

which will be an infinite loop but why it's working fine?
I didn't understand at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
let moveNearerToZero = chooseStepFunction(value: currentValue, backward: currentValue > 0)
```

Is only run *once*, since it is outside of the loop. So the branch `backward ? stepBackward : stepForward` is run only once. The code chose `stepBackward` once, and never again.

`let someName = someExpression` does not mean "from now on, every time I say `someName`, evaluate `someExpression`". It means "evaluate `someExpression`, and put the result into the constant called `someName`".

To achieve what you want, you can move the `chooseStepFunction` call into the loop:

```
while currentValue != -2 {
    print("\(currentValue)... ")
    let moveNearerToZero = chooseStepFunction(value: currentValue, backward: currentValue > 0)
    currentValue = moveNearerToZero(currentValue)
}
```